# Compare a vector with selected element from a matrix

Tags: r, vector, matrix, compare

I want to compare a huge vector with selected element from a matrix in R.

A is a matrix and B is a vector. I want to compare each element of B with selected element from A. C and D are selection criteria. They are vectors of same length as B. C specifies the row number of A, and D specifies the column number. A is of dimension 10*100, and B,C,D are all vectors of length 72000. Code with for loop:

```
for ( j in 1:length(B) ){
  E[j] <- B[j] >= A[ C[j], D[j] ]
}
```

This is too slow. I vectorize this by define a vector including elements from A first:

```
A1 <- array(0, length(B))
A2 <- A[,D]
for ( j in 1:length(B) ){
  A1[j] <- A2[ C[j], j ]
}   
E <- B >= A1
```

This is still too slow. Is there a better way to this?

Comment: May I ask if you found any of the three answers below of help?

Comment: I think all of them are helpful. The third one with cbind is faster in this case. However, if A is a 3 or higher dimensional array, then second is more suitable. I can use A[C,D,,] to subscript it. However, it is wrong to use A[cbind(C,D),,].

Comment: Just to clarify @lionup, if you subset an array by a single matrix (for example `A[cbind(C,D)]` you get a vector with one value for each row in A.  If you subset using multiple vectors (for example `A[C,D]`) you will receieve a `length(C)` x `length(D)` array.  Both are useful when appropriate but it is important to understand these are not the same!

Comment: Hi MatthewS, can you help me with a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721120/r-select-sequence-of-sub-matrix-from-a-high-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute fastest way I can think of is to treat A as a vector and extract the elements you want. A matrix *is* really just a vector with dimension attributes.  Arithmetic operations are extremely fast and the `[` subsetting operator is vectorised.

To get the desired elements all you need to do is multiply your desired column number (`D`) by the total number of rows and then subtract the desired row number (`C`) minus total number of rows, eg `A[ D * nrow(A) - ( nrow(A) - C) ]` as in this example:

```
set.seed(1234)
A <- matrix( sample(5,16,repl=TRUE) , 4 )
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    1    1    5
#[2,]    1    3    5    5
#[3,]    2    1    1    2
#[4,]    1    4    2    1

## Rows
C <- sample( nrow(A) , 3 , repl = TRUE )
#[1] 1 2 3

## Columns
D <- sample( ncol(A) , 3 , repl = TRUE )
#[1] 1 3 2

## Treat A as a vector
## Elements are given by:
rs <- nrow(A)
A[ D * rs - ( rs - C) ]
#[1] 2 5 1
```

Comment: From your answer, I learned a new way to subscript matrix. Thanks.

Comment: I find your method is really helpful in dealing with higher dimensional array.

Comment: @lionup I am glad you found it useful! Long live useR's

Answer (score 2):

You can easily select each element of A that corresponds to each entry of B, based on the selection criteria B and C.  Combine B and C into a two-column matrix, and then subset A with that matrix:

```
A.subset <- A[cbind(B, C)]
```

You now have a vector (A.subset) of the same length as B, and can perform whatever (vectorized) comparison you like in a performant manner.

Comment: I've never seen that use of `cbind` before. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally get your question, but I think you want something like the following:

```
# setup some mock data
a <- matrix(rnorm(1000,0,1),nrow=10, ncol=100)
b <- rnorm(100,0,1)
c <- rep(1:10,10)
d <- 1:100

# define function
compare <- function(v,row,column)
    return(v >= a[row,column]) # you might want this to output to something else

# apply the comparison function to the b, c, and d vectors
mapply(FUN=compare, b, c, d)
```

Comment: I compared your method with the method below. Your method takes 0.64 second, and the one below takes 0.52 second. However, I think your method can be used more generally in case that 'a' is not a matrix but a high dimensional array. Then I can use a[row,column,,,] to subscript it. Thanks.